# is this is javascript try catch block bug or something else

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, try-catch

```
export const ReduxSignInAsync =
  (usernameOrEmail, password,callback) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(ReduxStartSignIn());
    try {
      const response = await Backend.post("auth/sign-in", {
        usernameOrEmail,
        password
      });
      console.log('response: sign in', response); // this never log's the value

      if (response.status !== 200) return; // it doesn't return from here
      console.log('response.status: ', response.status); // never log's out
      if(response.status == 200) { 
        dispatch(ReduxSuccessSignIn(response.data?.token)); // this block runs every time i don't know why
        callback() // even with error it redirect's me to home page
      }
      return;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error: sign in', error); //this error log out
      if (error.response.status === 400) {
        dispatch(ReduxErrorSignIn("Wrong credentials provided"));
      } else if (error.response.status === 404) {
        dispatch(ReduxErrorSignIn("User not found. Try signing up"));
      } else {
        dispatch(ReduxErrorSignIn("Something is wrong. Try again later"));
      }
    }
  };
```

```
import axios from "axios";

const Backend = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL,
});

export default Backend;
```

This function i was using for signing-in in react redux.
The problem is if there is an error with server the code should be running the catch error section but it is running whole try block and whole catch block.
If there is no response then last else block should run but it run's whole function.

```
callback => navigate('/')
```

It always redirects to home page without receiving response from server.
the console log of response never prints and that if block is running I don't know how

this function return error but always redirect's me to home page which I don't want and I can't solve this from hours so need help???

Comment: What is this syntax? `const ReduxSignInAsync =
  (usernameOrEmail, password,callback) => async (dispatch) => {` should be one or the other, not 2 `=>`

Comment: you can safely assume the language doesn't have a bug, especially in something so fundamental :)

Comment: It's action for redux state management

Comment: If server is not sending response then why it run the full try block instead of directly catching errror...

Comment: is `Backend.post` code you wrote? If so, please show it. If not, what library is it from? (I'm just wondering if it will reject the promise on non-2xx codes, like `axios` does, or resolve the promise like `fetch` does)

Comment: It's a axios instance. I created. sorry for naming convention

Comment: it does not log the response why??? and also passes the **if** block where I check for status